# Show info to author only

Tags: posts, admin, author

I'm writing my own plugin.

works like this:

```
function myfunc (){
    $a = 'hello';
    // the sentence what Am looking for: 
    if ( user is logged and is the author of current post / page ){
        $a= 'author';
    }
    return $a; 
}
```

Wondering how I can do that sencence / function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare display names:

```
$currentuser = get_currentuserinfo();

if ( get_the_author() == $currentuser->displayname ) {
     // current user is the post author; do something
}
```

The `get_the_author()` function returns `displayname`, which should be able to be compared against the `displayname` parameter that is a part of the `$currentuser` object.

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

You can get this information using the current_user and post variables.

```
function myfunc (){
    global $current_user, $post;
    $a = 'hello';
    // check if current user id matches post author id
    if ( $current_user->ID == $post->post_author ){
        $a = 'author';
    }
    return $a; 
}
```